# Question:ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead

#Code

```
 initFormGroups(): void {
    const sectionGroups = {};
    this._sections.map((section: TemplateSection, sectionIndex: number) => {
      const sectionGroup = {};

      section.questions.map(({ rephrase, question, notes }: Question, questionIndex) => {
        sectionGroup[questionIndex] = [rephrase || question];
     
      });

      sectionGroups[sectionIndex] = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroup);

      return null;
    });

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroups);
  
  }
```

#template

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" name="form" *ngIf="form">
<mat-card class="question" *ngFor="let question of section.questions; let questionIndex = index">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="question.notes">

                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"
                        class="pr-4 clickable-mat-form-field"
                        (click)="editNote(sectionIndex, questionIndex, question)"
                      >
                        <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
                        <input class="hidden" matInput>
                          <editor class="mat-input-element"
                            [disabled]="true"
                            matInput [(ngModel)]="question.notes"
                            [init]="tinyMCEConfig"
                          >
                          </editor>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: replace ```[(ngModel])``` by ```formControlName```. You are using FormBuilder for initializing from model. Don't mix up ```Template Form``` and ```Reactive Form``` each other.

Comment: when I try ```formControlName ="question.notes"``` . Cannot find control with name: 'question.notes'

Comment: Please go for FormGroup, FormBuilder and FormArray concepts in angular. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @SantoshShinde , have updated my template.

Comment: can you create stackblitz so i can help you better. http://stackblitz.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218405/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-santosh-shinde).

Comment: I have a question how do i create a formcontrol for the notes ?

Comment: I think that must be: `this.form = this.formBuilder.array(sectionGroups);`, to create a FormArray, but I'm not sure. Furthermore, your .html has no structure to manage a formArray. tip: in .html write `{{form?.value|json}}` to see nearly the structure of the form to has some clue

Comment: @Eliseo can you ellaborate or post an answer of it Sir /

Comment: Read the documentation about formArrays, you can also check this link about formArrays from Netanel Basal: https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a I hope this help you to undestand the formArrays